# NoReverseMatch at /user_details/reset-password

Tags: django

I know it's well asked, but somehow none of the other answers seemed to solve my problem.

I get an error with the ReverseMatch, here is the relevant urls.py section:

```
# for password reset
    url(r'^reset-password$','django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset', {'post_reset_redirect' : 'user_details/reset_password.html', 'template_name': 'user_details/reset_password.html'}, name="password_reset"),
    url(r'^reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>.+)/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm', {'post_reset_redirect' : 'user_details/reset_password.html'}, name="password_reset_confirm"),
```

I think the name is adequately defined?

The problem is in the  template /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/registration/password_reset_email.html, error at line 6:

```
{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url 'password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}
```

where the {% url ...} is highlighted in red.

Why? 
I assume that Django would then use the default template for that view?

Thanks!

Chris

Comment: just to make sure its not something small like an oversight of some kind, can you hit the /reset/uidb64/token endpoint in your browser? Just want to make sure you have the url in your url loading path.

Comment: This worked fine. I simply pasted the values into the URL and BINGO, loads the default page.

Comment: Can you paste your uidb64 in a comment? And also which django version you are on?

Comment: @TitusP My uidb64 is: MQ the Django version is 1.7.6.

Comment: Did you try using Django's build in auth URLs to see if those work (just try urlpatterns = [
    url('^', include('django.contrib.auth.urls'))
])? Just looking at the docs vs your URL, it looks like your not matching correctly. 

The url pattern in the built in admin is ^reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$

Comment: Sorry @TitusP, I tried that but the error remains the same. Also you have a non-ASCII character in your response. I do not know which one as I typed the string again as per your suggestion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93739/discussion-between-dengar81-and-titus-p).

Comment: So the error is definitely with the default Django file, as when I override the url part in the email.html it seems to work.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace that is generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, I had to resolve to overwriting the Django default email, because the reverse URL lookup doesn't want to behave properly.

So I created a copy of the original Django email file (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/registration/password_reset_email.html):

```
{% load i18n %}{% autoescape off %}
{% blocktrans %}You're receiving this email because you requested a password reset for your user account at {{ site_name }}.{% endblocktrans %}

{% trans "Please go to the following page and choose a new password:" %}
{% block reset_link %}
{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url 'password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}
{% endblock %}
{% trans "Your username, in case you've forgotten:" %} {{ user.get_username }}

{% trans "Thanks for using our site!" %}

{% blocktrans %}The {{ site_name }} team{% endblocktrans %}

{% endautoescape %}
```

and replaced line 6 with the following:

```
{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}/user_details/reset/{{uid}}/{{token}}
```

which matches my urls.py.

This does indeed work now...

Answer (score 0):

You have defined a URL which accepts a "uidb36" parameter, but the reverse call is passing "uidb64".

Comment: Thanks that was my oversight, but it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Really? Then something is happening that you're not showing. How are you including those urls you show?

Comment: Not really sure I understand the question. I use django.conf.urls import url, patters, include urlpatterns = [...]